# Get the first instance of a letter from the string

Tags: java, string, char

I am working on this very simple method I know I am very close to finish it, but I am missing a detail. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
/**
  Gets the first letter in this string.
  @return the FIRST LETTER, or "" if there are no letters.
  add1=AD3F add2=EF4G result=32SFB  (BUT THESE ARE RANDOM ONLY INTS AND CHARS)
*/
public String firstLetter()
{
    String line = add1+add2+result;

    for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
    char ch=new Character(line.charAt(i));
    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
        System.out.println("This is the first letter"+ch);
        return ch;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No it is not a character: "+ch);
    return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `else` code outside the loop so that it is only executed when you have tested all of the characters:

```
public class FirstLetter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(firstLetter());
    }

    public static String firstLetter()
    {
        String line = "AD3F" + "EF4G" + "32SFB";

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            {
                System.out.println("This is the first letter: " + ch);
                return Character.toString(ch);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("No character found");
        return "";
    }
}
```

This kind of problem is more obvious when you format the code clearly.

I have kept the return type as `String` as per your original, but see also Jon Skeet's comments about changing that to `char`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mr. DNA. I also learned from your code the casting "return Character.toString(ch)" I was going to do it in two steps, but you showed me how to do it in one step. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your return type is `String`, but you're only trying to return a single *character*. Why not make it return a `char`, with `\0` as the "no characters" return value - or possibly throwing an exception...

You also need to think about the ends of blocks - your `if` statement, your `else` clause, the loop, and the method itself. I would *strongly* recommend:

- Using braces for all cases, even when there's only a single statement in the block (as per the `else` clause
- Paying attention to indentation. It makes all the difference in clarity for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Skeet I made the changes that you adviced me. As a beginner in java I must practice indentation, after the changes I could see it more clear. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic should look like this:

```
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        ch = new Character(line.charAt(i));
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            System.out.println("This is the first letter" + ch);
            return String.valueOf(ch);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No letters, sorry.")
    return "";
```

As soon as a letter is found, it is reported and returned. But if the end of the end of the `line` is reached (i.e. the `for` loop completes), then obviously no letter was found, so report that and return an empty string.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Corbett. Very helpful your advice. I appreciate it.